# grails facebook registration/login

Tags: grails, groovy, facebook, spring-security

I have a Grails app that uses the Spring Security plugin for authorisation/authentication. I would like to also offer users the ability to register/login via Facebook. I need to integrate Facebook login/registration with the Spring Security plugin, such that (for example) if I call

```
springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
```

it will return a user object for the current user regardless of whether that user logged-in with Facebook.

I've found a [variety](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) of [plugins](https://github.com/pinut/grails-spring-security-facebook) and [blog-posts](http://alexduan.com/2011/08/23/grails-spring-security-facebook-in-depth-guide/) that propose a solution, but I'm not sure which (if any) will work with the most recent version of Grails (2.0.0.RC1) and the Spring Security plugin.

Can anyone recommend which of these plugins/procedures I should try or should I just work with the Facebook API directly? I read somewhere that using a plugin may be inadvisable, because the Facebook API changes frequently (and there will inevitable be a gap between the time Facebook make these changes and when a compatible version of the plugin is released).

Comment: did you gather any more info on this subject?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I can't be unbiased there, because I'm the author of http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook

Btw, can say that this plugin is compatible with Grails 2.0RC1. And i've an grails 2.0 project using this plugins.

PS I you have any questions or found a bug - you can contact me directly

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the ["blog-posts"](http://alexduan.com/2011/08/23/grails-spring-security-facebook-in-depth-guide/) you linked above, I'll say that my guide was done using a Grails 2.0 milestone release and should work with the latest release of Grails and Spring Security.

The spring-security-facebook plugin worked when I tried it last and probably (now) has the latest OAuth2.0 fixes in place, but at the time of the writing for my post, those changes were still in progress.

The choice between using the plugin and not using the plugin is really a balancing act between convenience and control. While Facebook's API changes will probably slow down as the platform matures, which should give people more confidence in the plugin, there will always be inherent risks when adding these additional layers of abstraction.

For me, I found the implementation of Facebook and Spring Security relatively trivial and prefer the extra control knowing that if/when the Facebook API changes, I or one of my developers can go and address the change without having to rely on a third-party, plugin support team has time to fix my issues.